# How does the game world react to you murdering everyone?

Tags: dishonored-2

In the first *Dishonored* game, chaos rose and the effects of the plague were more widespread if you murdered everybody. Does *Dishonored 2* have a similar mechanic? After 20 minutes of play I already badly want to murder a bunch of these jerks and am looking for some sort of reason not to do so.

What changes in the game if you go on a killing rampage?

Comment: Is Dishonored 2 even out yet? The release date for the game is scheduled for the 11th.

Comment: Through changing your timezone and using sophisticated VPN you can, yes.

Comment: If you preordered, you could play the 10th. It released on Steam at midnight last night. Consoles as well. I played for about 20 minutes last night before heading to bed.

Comment: The title would be better if it was "Would the world react to me murdering everyone?" ;)

Comment: I see now in the saved game menu that the game has chaos, like the first one, and the journal says I'll get more chaos for murdering my first target than taking them out non-lethally, so at this point I guess it's not a question of "if" the game changes, but how it changes. I've updated the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 3):

From my observations so far in the early-mid game (I finished up to mission 4 in high chaos, mission 2 in low chaos, watched some different streams / videos up to mission 4) :

A large part of the dialogs stay the same, but some dialogs change (dialogs during cutscenes, notably with the Outsider, and during mission intro / outro).  For example the intro to the 4th mission ends with "Save one genius, cage the other" in low chaos, "Save one genius, kill the other" in high chaos.

Some events change and small parts of the levels change. For exemple in the second mission there is a small back alley with a patrolling overseer in low chaos which is infested by bloodflies and blocked off (with the overseer dead inside) in high chaos.

A few comments by the heart also change.

Changes happen as soon as the second mission. You don't need to wait for the end game to see a difference.

The game advertises this in a loading screen / tutorial thingy like the first game: more dead people leads to a bleaker world, more bloodflies and a darker ending.